# My program stops working from a while loop when using dynamic allocated lists

Tags: c++

I've been studying about dynamic allocated lists (the stuff we are discussing right now in class is pretty outdated tbh) and I can't seem to access the next node in a list. (I've just began learning this topic)

The problem is that the while loop that I'm using for going through the list never stops. I'm definitely missing something and I don't understand what.

```
struct node {
    int info;
    node* next;
};

int main()
{
    node *p, *prim=NULL;
    p = prim;
    node* t;
    t = new node;
    p->next = t;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        cout << "test";
        p = p -> next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the code.

Why does my program not output anything and also tells me "it exited with code -1073741819" instead of 0?

Thanks.

////edit: I forgot to tell you that I've tried this way too

```
struct node {
    int info;
    node* next;
};

int main()
{
    node *p, *prim=NULL;
    p = prim;
    node* t;
    t = new node;
    prim->next = t;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        cout << "test";
        p = p -> next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't `p` equal to `NULL`?

Comment: In the first place yes. PRIM is supposed to be the head of the list. After that I've set p->next to the next node (in this case, t) which I suppose also sets the head->next to t, because p = prim. (Am I right?)

Comment: ***set p->next to the next node*** You can't do that because p is NULL

Comment: @JohnSmith You can't set `p->next` because there is no `p` for which to set a `next`. You can't use `->` on a null pointer.

Comment: @drescherjm so I should initialize either p or either the head (which is PRIM in my code). Is that right?

Comment: You can just get rid of `t`, and use `prim` directly. After you set `prim`, then you would do `p = prim`, but not before. Also, the value of `next` is unknown. in `node`, you should do `node *next = nullptr`

Comment: After fixing the null dereference you should also put some data into the `info` field.

Comment: In my mind, prim is the head (which I don't want to make changes to because then I can't access the list anymore), p is the pointer which I use for accessing each node, and t is for declaring the second node. Am I missing something?

Comment: Part of your problem is there is no second node when you don't have a first node yet.

Comment: You may find it helpful to create a [mre] before writing your question. In this case, for example, creating a MRE should reveal that you can eliminate your loop and still get the strange exit status. Further narrowing down should reveal that the statement trying to set `->next` is the failure point. This information would change much of the text of your question. *(Admittedly, other people fare far worse as far as MREs go. You're close enough that just a little extra effort should get you to a good spot.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to setup a basic linked list and loop through it. Your loop looks good, but you forgot the part where you actually setup the list!

That could look like:

```
struct node {
    int info;
    node* next;
    //Add a quick constructor to make creating new nodes easy
    node(int i) : info(i), next(nullptr) { }
};

int main()
{
    //Start out with 3 itmes
    // This list will look like:
    //    head -> 5 -> 3 -> 1
    node *head = new node(5);
    head->next = new node(3);
    head->next->next = new node(1);

    //Loop through the list and print each value
    for(node *p = head; p; p = p->next) {
        std::cout << p->info << std::endl;
    }

    //Don't forget to delete the memory you allocated to prevent a leak!
    for(node *p = head; p;) {
        node *temp = p->next;
        delete p;
        p = temp;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

See it run: https://ideone.com/WngD3b

Comment: I didn't run into constructors yet. Can you remove that part and edit your code so it doesn't use that line?

Comment: @John the constructor is just a fancy and easy way to set `info` to whatever I pass it, and `next` to `nullptr`. You could do that manually in the body of `main()` if you wanted like `node *head = new node; head->info = 5; head->next = nullptr;`. But for anyone with your same question in the future, I'd rather leave my answer as the "right" and cleanest way to do this.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thank you for your time, I understand now.

Answer (score 4):

Let's analyze your code:

```
node *p, *prim=NULL;     // prim is NULL, p not yet initnialized
p = prim;                // p now equal to NULL as well
node* t;
t = new node;            // t is allocated
p->next = t;             // NULL->next = t
```

So you're crashing on a null pointer when you try to dereference `p->next` for assignment.

Comment: So I needed to initialize prim instead of setting it to NULL? How should the head of the list be defined?

Comment: Depends on what you want your program to do.  You should tell me that so I can give better advice. :)

Comment: I've studied lists a long time ago and I am clearly lost right now. I'm trying to re-learn them. Basically, this should be a basic dynamic list (with head and tail) where each of the 'info' member of the struct contains a number. I have to output each of that number.